# Why chomp($Array[0]) will delete the some string contain in $Array[0]?

Tags: perl

I have a input file which is look like this

```
1a0i b.40.4.6
1a49 b.58.1.1
1a82 c.37.1.10
1atp d.144.1.7
.
.
.
.
```

---

Problem1

I put each line into @Array

when I use

```
$Line = chomp($Array[0]);
print $Line;
```

show the output in screen 1

```
but When I use
$Line = $Array[0];
print $Line;
```

show the output in screen 1a0i b.40.4.6

Why the chomp will let $Line remaining only one character?

---

Problem2

I want to use b.40 as a file_name , so here it's my code

$Array[0] is 1a0i   b.40.4.6

```
$Line = $Array[0];
@Element = split(" ",$Line);
@Tiny_element = split(".",$Element[1]);
$File_name = join(".",splice(@Tiny_element,0,2));
```

but I print $File_name , but it show nothing , I use `Dumper \@Tiny_element` , but it show empty
I `print $Element[1]` , it shows b.40.4.6 , I use `index($Element[1],".")` it show 1 so I know it contain "." but it can't separate with "."

I try `split("\.",$Element[1])` ; `split('.',$Element[1])` before , but it still don't solve out ....

What's wrong with it?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer to problem 1:**

Use:

```
chomp($Array[0]);
$Line = $Array[0];
```

instead of:

```
$Line = chomp($Array[0]);
```

That's because return value of `chomp` is not the string, but the number of trailing characters removed from the string.

**Answer to problem 2**

```
$File_name = $1 if ($Line =~ /\s([^\.]+\.[^\.]+)/);
```

Comment: If you know that, what was the question again? BTW, I've added answer to your second question.

Comment: I just know that .....I know it's redicuous .. but I don't know that before I ask that .

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you could try reading the documentation for a function that you are using, rather than just guessing at its behaviour.

The [documentation for chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) says this:

> It returns the total number of characters removed from all its arguments

The string is edited in place.

Comment: I read the book and finally I get the answer for problem2 I should use @Tiny_element = split("\\.",$Element[1]);

Comment: The first argument to `split` is a regular expression. If you write it within `/.../` rather than `"..."` then you might be more likely to remember that :-)

Answer (score 1):

For your 2nd problem, If I were to clarify your code by changing the 1st parameter of your split statements as follows:

```
 $Line = $Array[0];
 @Element = split(/ /,$Line);
 @Tiny_element = split(/./,$Element[1]);
 $File_name = join(".",splice(@Tiny_element,0,2));
```

and reminded you that `.` is a wildcard character in regular expressions, would you better understand your error?

BTW: `/[.]/` is a great regex for finding literal periods.